# MVVM WPF value in view is null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am still very new to WPF and trying to grasp the MVVM pattern. I have the mainWindow.xaml file that has 2 datepickers

```
        <DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5"
                    Text="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.openDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock  Padding="5,5,5,5" Text=" to "/>
        <DatePicker Padding="5,5,5,5" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=dateOptObj.closeDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

when the program loads my date obj has valid data based on these datepickers and loads a grid matching these 2 dates:

```
dateOptObj = new mdDateOptions();
```

now this is the actual class that loads that object.

```
private ICollectionView _datOpts;
    public ObservableCollection<string> dates { get; private set; }
    public ICollectionView datesView
    {
        get
        {
            return _datOpts;
        }
    }
    public mdDateOptions()
    { 

        dates = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        dates.Add("Rolling Year");
        dates.Add("Year to Date");
        dates.Add("Last Year");

        _datOpts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dates);
        _datOpts.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(OnCurrentChanged);
    }

    public void OnCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currSel = (string)_datOpts.CurrentItem;
        DateTime p_date = new DateTime();
        p_date = DateTime.Today;

        switch (currSel)
        {
            case "Rolling Year":
                openDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
                closeDate = DateTime.Today;

                openDatePrevious = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2);
                closeDatePrevious = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);

                break;
            case "Year to Date":
                openDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
                closeDate = DateTime.Today;

                openDatePrevious = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year, 1, 1);
                closeDatePrevious = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
                break;
            case "Last Year":
                openDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year, 1, 1);
                closeDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).Year, 12, 31);

                openDatePrevious = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year, 1, 1);
                closeDatePrevious = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2).Year, 12, 31);
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Unknown Date Option");
                break;
        }
    }
```

my problem is that I have a userControl on my mainWindow.xaml which has a list of buttons that loads a grid on the mainWindow.xaml. when you hit a button in the userControl I want it to filter out certain data in the grid based on the datepickers but when my relay command fires in the viewmodel the dateOptObj above is null. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Below is how I am loading the UserControl.

```
<vm:StatPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Loaded="StatPanel_Loaded" />
```

Below is my UserControl panel that has the grid of buttons which i want to filter on the main grid in the MainWindow.xaml.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Security">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="Security" Content="{Binding Path=totalSecurities}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=filterGridCommand}">
                                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PassThroughConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="sector"/>
                                            <Binding ElementName="Security" Path="Name"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.CommandParameter>

                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and this is my filterGridCommand

```
public RelayCommand filterGridCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_filterGridCommand == null)
            {
                _filterGridCommand = new RelayCommand(filterGrid);
            }

            return _filterGridCommand;
        }
    }
    private void filterGrid(object param)
    {
        var values = (object[])param;
        string sector = (string)values[0];
        string type = (string)values[1];


        EmployeeObj empObj = (EmployeeObj)_repsView.CurrentItem;
        dash.reFillLogNewAccounts(dateOptObj.openDate, dateOptObj.closeDate, empObj.RRNumber,sector,type);
    }
```

Comment: I think you're showing the wrong bit of code.

Comment: I have added the code now. I apologize.

Comment: "dates.Add("Last Year");" you add strings to a dates collection? that doesn't look too good. Try to find good variable names.

Comment: Where is the ViewModel ?

Comment: this has parts of the viewmodel where the filtergrid gets hit! once it falls in to their the dateOptObj is null. The dateOptObj is loaded as shown above. once program loads it has valid dates in the obj but at the time that the filtergridcommand is hit the object is null.